# How can I create a dictionary where the key,value pairs are both integers with to_dict()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dictionary from a data set with two columns where 'col A' is my key and 'col B' is my value

```
A B 
8 12
9 22
10 25
```

but when i use the .to_dict('list') method my value in the dictionary is in the form of a list and doesn't work with the method later on in my code - heres what I'm doing to create my dictionary

```
d = df.set_index('A').T.to_dict('list')
```

with output

```
{7.5: [3], 8.0: [19], 8.5: [14], 9.0: [16], 9.5: [16], 10.0: [24]}
```

My question is how can I create a dictionary in this format but so that the values within the pairs are not in a list? like this:

```
{7.5: 3, 8.0: 19, 8.5: 14, 9.0: 16, 9.5: 16, 10.0: 24
```

Thanks!

Comment: Um, `df.set_index('A').T.to_dict('list')` gives `{8: [12], 9: [22], 10: [25]}`....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah sorry i took the code from my project because I'm lazy.. it was more about the format

Answer (score 2):

If you have dataframe:

```
    A   B
0   8  12
1   9  22
2  10  25
```

Then to create a dictionary where column "A" are keys and "B" values:

```py
dct = dict(zip(df.A, df.B))
print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{8: 12, 9: 22, 10: 25}
```

---

Or: (to have Python datatypes):

```py
dct = dict(zip(df.A.tolist(), df.B.tolist()))
```

Comment: Yeah, but you should use `df.A.tolist()` and `df.B.tolist()` to convert to python datatypes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Added it to my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [8, 9, 10], 'B': [12, 22, 25]})
```

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index) + [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html#pandas-series-to-dict):

```
d = df.set_index('A')['B'].to_dict()
```

`d`:

```
{8: 12, 9: 22, 10: 25}
```